# How can I add a 2D matrix in R as a dataframe variable?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I am trying to use the PLS library in order to run Partial Least Squares Regression. I imported my data from MATLAB with 'R.matlab' library.
One of my matrices I managed to insert to a dataframe quite easily since it was a 1D vector. It showed as

> my_1d_matrix  ...  num [1:205, 1] 124 138 38 76 155 ...

My other matrix however is **205x4096**. And it shows like this in my workspace:

> my_2d_matrix ... Large list (205 elements, 6.5 Mb)

How can I insert this as my second variable in the same dataframe?

From the [PLS introductory pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pls/vignettes/pls-manual.pdf), I see that the 'gasoline' dataset they use, consists of 'octane' (a 1d vector) and 'NIR' (a 2D large matrix), so I want to do the same with my data. Therefore, I thought that I should have the same format for my 2D matrix as this:

```
> library(pls)
> data(gasoline)    
> str(gasoline$NIR)
```

which is:

```
>AsIs [1:60, 1:401] -0.050193 -0.044227 -0.046867 -0.046705 -0.050859 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:60] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:401] "900 nm" "902 nm" "904 nm" "906 nm" ...
```

So the end result should be a dataframe similar to 'gasoline', where the *first* variable is **my_1d_matrix** and the *second* one is **my_2d_matrix**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your data is read into a list, i.e. your 2d matrix and the response variable is a matrix. To put both into a data frame you can try:

```
myData <- data.frame(y = my_1d_matrix)
myMat <- matrix(0,205,4096)
for(i in 1:205){
  myMat[i,] <- my_2d_matrix[[i]]
}
myData <- cbind(myData,myMat)
```

Now you should be able to call `plsr`:

```
myModel <- plsr(y ~ ., ncomp = 10, data = myData)
```

The dot `.` just means *use all the variables*, because there are no names specified in the `myData` data frame, which probably have names as a numeric.

If this doesn't work, then it is most likely because `my_2d_matrix[[i]]` contains something more then just a numeric vector.

You might want to specify the names of the variables in the data frame, the first column is the response, and the rest are the ones from your large matrix.

Comment: I get "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix" referring to the line `myMat[i,] <- my_2d_matrix[[i]]`

Comment: @kalfasyan what is the output of : `class(my_2d_matrix[[1]])` and `dim(my_2d_matrix[[1]])`?

Comment: It is `"list"` and `NULL` respectively. [Here is a screenshot of my_2d_matrix](http://imgur.com/sA3UATX)

Comment: Try this inside the for loop: `myMat[i,] <- matrix(unlist(my_2d_matrix[[i]]),1,4096)`

Comment: It worked mate. You're a genious! Thanks a lot. Seriously. I spent many hours on a seemingly trivial thing :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I gave you an upvote, you can start building your rep here :)